# Can I simplify this MERGE statement w.r.t. WHEN MATCHED conditions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I'm using SQL Server (SQL Server 2016 and Azure SQL) and I have this `MERGE` statement which uses a rather gnarly `WHEN MATCHED` condition to only update rows where values are actually different.

This is done for two reasons:

1. The table has a `rowversion` column that will change when an `UPDATE` operation is performed, even if all of the values are the same. The `rowversion` values are useful for reducing client-activity (the application uses `rowversion` for optimistic concurrency).
2. The table is also a Temporal Table, and SQL Server's implementation of Temporal Tables will add copies of live data to the History table whenever an `UPDATE` is performed, even if no values are actually changed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpsertItems
    @groupId int,
    @items   dbo.ItemsList READONLY -- This is a table-valued parameter. The UDT Table-Type has the same design as the `dbo.Items` table.

WITH existing AS    -- Using a CTE as the MERGE target to allow *safe* use of `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE` and apparently it's good for performance.
(
    SELECT
        groupId,
        itemId,
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        e,
        f,
        -- etc
    FROM
        dbo.Items
    WHERE
        groupId = @groupId
)
MERGE INTO existing WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS tgt
USING
    @items AS src ON tgt.itemId = src.itemId
WHEN MATCHED AND
(
    -- This part is painful, but unfortunately these are all NULLable columns so they need the full `x IS DISTINCT FROM y`-equivalent comparison:

    ( ( tgt.a <> src.a OR tgt.a IS NULL OR src.a IS NULL ) AND NOT ( tgt.a IS NULL AND src.a IS NULL ) )
    OR
    ( ( tgt.b <> src.b OR tgt.b IS NULL OR src.b IS NULL ) AND NOT ( tgt.b IS NULL AND src.b IS NULL ) )
    OR
    ( ( tgt.c <> src.c OR tgt.c IS NULL OR src.c IS NULL ) AND NOT ( tgt.c IS NULL AND src.c IS NULL ) )
    OR
    ( ( tgt.d <> src.d OR tgt.d IS NULL OR src.d IS NULL ) AND NOT ( tgt.d IS NULL AND src.d IS NULL ) )
    OR
    ( ( tgt.e <> src.e OR tgt.e IS NULL OR src.e IS NULL ) AND NOT ( tgt.e IS NULL AND src.e IS NULL ) )
    OR
    ( ( tgt.f <> src.f OR tgt.f IS NULL OR src.f IS NULL ) AND NOT ( tgt.f IS NULL AND src.f IS NULL ) )
    -- etc
)
THEN UPDATE SET
    tgt.a = src.a,
    tgt.b = src.b,
    tgt.c = src.c,
    tgt.d = src.d,
    tgt.e = src.e,
    tgt.f = src.f,
    -- etc
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (
    groupId,
    itemId,
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
    f,
    -- etc
)
VALUES (
    src.groupId,
    src.itemId,
    src.a,
    src.b,
    src.c,
    src.d,
    src.e,
    src.f,
    -- etc
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE

OUTPUT
    $action AS [Action],

    inserted.groupId AS Ins_groupId,
    deleted .groupId AS Del_groupId,
    inserted.itemId  AS Ins_itemId,
    deleted .itemId  AS Del_itemId,
    inserted.a       AS Ins_a,
    deleted .a       AS Del_a,
    inserted.b       AS Ins_b,
    deleted .b       AS Del_b,
    inserted.c       AS Ins_c,
    deleted .c       AS Del_c,
    inserted.d       AS Ins_d,
    deleted .d       AS Del_d,
    inserted.e       AS Ins_e,
    deleted .e       AS Del_e,
    inserted.f       AS Ins_f,
    deleted .f       AS Del_f,
    -- etc
;
```

As you can see, this is quit the pain to maintain!

I already use tools like T4 to automate generating the repetitive parts of this query, but the sheer... scale and *pain* of this `MERGE` statement makes me feel like I'm doing something very wrong (because software is meant to light-the-way via [the Pit of Success](https://blog.codinghorror.com/falling-into-the-pit-of-success/), so if one is encountering difficulties trying to do *the right thing* you're probably *doing it wrong*), but I can't think or see a better way of accomplishing this (`BULK INSERT` notwithstanding, but for the purposes of this question that's not a possibility).

I know this statement can be simplified in other RDBMS which support `x IS DISTINCT FROM y` (which replaces the horrible-but-necessary `NULL`-safe checks in the `WHEN MATCHED AND`, [but SQL Server **still** doesn't support it](https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from).

Another pain is the lack of DRY in SQL in general - and the difficulty of implementing a DRY database in SQL Server (e.g. there's no support for Deferred Constraints or Table Inheritance so you can't implement the Subclass Table Pattern, which means needless repetition of data-design in multiple tables and weaker constraints) - but that's another topic. I'm just frustrated with how *backward* SQL programming seems today compared to the many time-saving and keypress-saving features in modern languages like Kotlin and TypeScript.

### Fantasy time:

I'd love to be able to do something like this, and not have to do with any gotchas (like how `MERGE` is unsafe by default without an explicit `HOLDLOCK` - that's crazy!):

```
MERGE INTO
    dbo.Items AS tgt
WHERE
    tgt.groupId = @groupId
FROM
    @items AS src
ON
    tgt.itemId = src.itemId
WHEN MATCHED AND DIFFERENT THEN UPDATE ( automap )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ( automap )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
OUTPUT ALL;
```

(Where `automap` would be an amazing feature in SQL Server that automatically maps source and destination columns by name and throws a compile-time error if it cannot automatically and *safely* map columns to each other), and `OUTPUT ALL` would output all `$action`, `inserted`, and `deleted` values with different column names - using the same column names but with `inserted` and `deleted` values in adjacent rows).

Answer (score 2):

Use of `EXCEPT` is the best option, as noted by Brian, but this can be using directly in the `MERGE` as follows:

```
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS(
    SELECT src.*
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT tgt.*
    )
```

Here is a full working example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test
CREATE TABLE #TEST (
    A INT PRIMARY KEY,
    B INT, 
    C INT,
)

INSERT INTO #Test 
    VALUES (1, 1, 1)
        ,(2, 1, 1)
        ,(3, 1, 1)
        ,(4, 1, NULL)
        ,(5, 1, NULL)
        ,(6, 1, NULL)

;WITH NewValues AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES (2, 0, 1) --Update
            ,(3, 1, 1) -- Do Nothing
            ,(4, 0, NULL) -- UPDATE
            ,(5, 1, NULL) -- Do nothing, NULL = NULL
            ,(6, 1, 1) -- UPDATE 
            ,(7, 1, 1) -- INSERT
    ) V(A, B, C)
)
MERGE INTO #Test As t
USING 
    NewValues AS S ON t.A = s.A
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS(
    -- New values Exist Expcet when the match the old values exactly
    SELECT s.B, s.C 
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT t.B, t.C
    )
THEN UPDATE SET
    t.B = s.B,  t.C = s.C
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT(
    A,  B,  C
) VALUES (s.A, s.B, s.C)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
OUTPUT
    $action AS [Action],
    inserted.*,
    deleted.*;

SELECT * FROM #TEST
```

Comment: Interesting! I'll be able to try this out with production data later in the week. I'll reply when I see how it does.

Comment: Did not think of that. Wonder how it optimizes compared to the approach I have been using.

Comment: I'd ask that you considering supporting this mssql change: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/39699781-updates-only-on-changed-data, to minimize this type of pattern in general.  Adding a comment to extend it to MERGE statements wouldn't be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do deletes separately and get the data to be added or updated using an `EXCEPT` query.

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f FROM SOURCE
EXCEPT
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f FROM DESTINATION
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score -4):

You can get something like "IS DISTINCT FROM" using CONCAT function.

WHEN MATCHED AND CONCAT(tgt.a, tgt.b, tgt.c, tgt.d, tgt.e, tgt.f) <> (src.a, src.b, src.c, src.d, src.e, src.f) THEN UPDATE....

Comment: This is a bad idea for too many reasons (e.g. it won't detect the difference between `NULL` and empty-strings, it will have poor performance at-scale, it may have issues with string values exceeding 4000 characters in length, it won't detect the difference between `a = 1, b = 10` vs. `a = 11, b = 0`, etc)..

Comment: there is something wrong if you have to compare more than 4000 characters here... :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! This might be better as a comment? You could flag it for a moderator to change it into one. Personally, I'm in favour of having a moderated queue for new users to be able to comment - I suggested this but was shot down :-(.